# BFGMiner for Debian Wheezy

Tags: linux, bfgminer, mining-software

Is it possible to install BFGMiner on Debian Wheezy?

I have been looking for a solution but I can't find one.

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: There is no specific package for download that I can find for debian. They are for Ubuntu

Comment: So, you build it from source.  There's a nice README in the source package.  There's even a README.Debian discussing how to make it into your own debian package.

Comment: Really? Ill check it out

Answer (score 2):

Download the bfgminer source code, extract the source, change directory into it.

Then:

$ dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us -rfakeroot

And it'll build a package you can install on Debian Wheezy. You will need to install "dpkg-dev" for dpkg-buildpackage and all the build dependencies, which you'll find out by running the dpkb-buildpackage command.

Answer (score -2):

you have to patch it first before building the package;

`patch -p1 < debian/patches/bfgminer-bitforce.diff`

Comment: No, dpkg-buildpackages will install patches in debian/patches by itself.